# Interactively adding text / image to a PDF file

Tags: pdf

I have a requirement for a feature for adding text / images to a PDF file in our WPF application.

I am looking for any free / commercial controls that allow the following tasks:

[1] identify the coordinates, page location where to drop the text / image (preferably by converting mouse location to PDF/page location)

[2] embed text / image in the selected location (currently doable with free PDF api's)

[3] undo placed text / image or move it dynamically (latter is preferred)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the program Livecycle to add interactice text in my PDF's

First I creat the dokument in InDesign then I make it to a PDF. Open LiveCykle insert the textboxes save as PDF.

Then you open Acrobat pro and choose Advanced > Enable User Rights....

In Livecykle you also have the opertunity to insert at imagebox - when the user clicks in the field it opens the explorer on the pc, so you can browse after a JPG picture

There're diffirent options on how the picture should be scaled in the imagebox

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The requirement is that there is no preset location to perform the edit. The user will be specifying the locations where to annotate the document with an image or text.